# group by the oldest and newest SQLITE

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, kotlin

I have this two queries:

Query 1:

```
select afp, 
max(fecha) as fecha
from valcuota 
where afp ='MODELO'
UNION
select afp, 
date(max(fecha),'-31 days') as fecha
from valcuota 
where afp ='MODELO'
```

[image: Query1]

---

Query 2

```
select strftime('%m-%Y',periodo) as periodo_str, fondo,periodo
from (select fondo, periodo 
from movimientos
group by fondo , periodo
order by count(periodo) desc
) temp where temp.fondo = fondo
group by periodo_str 
order by periodo desc
limit 2
```

[image: Query 2]

and I need to join them in such a way that the oldest and the newest date of query1.fecha is associated with query2.periodo

this is what i need

---

[image: Query3]

Comment: It would help your question to rephrase it by instead showing the starting table data along with the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` in each query to create a common column on which you will join them:

```
select
  t2.periodo_str, t2.fondo, t2.periodo, t1.afp, t1.fecha 
from (
  select t.*, row_number() over (order by t.fecha) rn
  from (
    select afp, 
    max(fecha) as fecha
    from valcuota 
    where afp ='MODELO'
    UNION
    select afp, 
    date(max(fecha),'-31 days') as fecha
    from valcuota 
    where afp ='MODELO'
  ) t
) t1 inner join  (
  select t.*,  row_number() over (order by t.periodo) rn
  from ( 
    select strftime('%m-%Y',periodo) as periodo_str, fondo,periodo
    from (
      select fondo, periodo 
      from movimientos
      group by fondo, periodo
      order by count(periodo) desc
    ) temp where temp.fondo = fondo
    group by periodo_str 
    order by periodo desc
    limit 2
  ) t
) t2 on t2.rn = t1.rn
```

Comment: thx, this works in SQLite browse, but doesn't work in Android Studio 

`android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "(": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR[1]): ,`

Comment: This code answers the question as you posted it. If you have a problem with Android Studio post a new question.